# Remove slashes and quotes

Tags: regex, ansible

I've written the following Ansible to access Azure for automation I'm building.

This is the output,    `"msg": "\"6d23f7f3-b712-421d-a911-ec73cd18ff8b\", \"ansible\", \"Wfq5-rdMKpv_5HWvr5SJzkzMVfnExVRpv_\", \"5f6e5ef8-7687-487b-a682-15830393472b\""`
I want to  remove the slashes and quotes in order to use the values in the create-for-rbac command.

Also, I don't know whether I can loop through set_facts instead of having 4-separate commands.

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:

  #{
  #  "appId": "6d23f7f3-b712-421d-a911-ec73cd18ff8b",
  #  "displayName": "ansible",
  #  "password": "tsiQh~gR4S-IBHi8VBoPtWlYTS~r~jE8KF",
  #  "tenant": "5f6e5ef8-7687-487b-a682-15830393472b"
  #}

  - name:
    command: az ad sp create-for-rbac --name ansible --role Contributor
    register: rbac

  - name:
    set_fact:
      appId: "{{ rbac.stdout_lines.1.split().1 }}"
  - name:
    set_fact:
      displayName: "{{ rbac.stdout_lines.2.split().1 }}"
  - name:
    set_fact:
      password: "{{ rbac.stdout_lines.3.split().1 }}"
  - name:
    set_fact:
      tenant: "{{ rbac.stdout_lines.4.split().1 }}"

  - name:
    debug:
      msg: "{{ appId }} {{ displayName }} {{ password }} {{ tenant }}"


#  - name: Create an Azure service principal
#    command: az login --service-principal -u "{{ myAppID }}" -p "{{ mypasswd }}" --tenant "{{ mytenant }}"
```

Comment: Looks like this will work. 
    set_fact:
      tenant: "{{ rbac.stdout_lines.4.split().1 | regex_replace('\"', '') }}"

Comment: Also you can set all the variables with only one call to set_fact

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html#examples

Comment: This looks suspiciously like you're taking JSON output from a command and trying to manually mangle it instead of parsing it as JSON. You should probably be doing something more like `appId: "{{ (rbac.stdout | from_json).appId }}"`

Answer (score 1):

hi i think this should work: (?<=["\])\b.*?\b(?=["\])

My Exemple : https://regex101.com/r/rb2Sq9/1